# Time Limit Exceeded on Leetcode 512. Game Play Analysis II

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table information**:

```
| player_id    | int     |
| device_id    | int     |
| event_date   | date    |
| games_played | int     |
+--------------+---------+
```

*(player_id, event_date) is the primary key of this table.
This table shows the activity of players of some games.
Each row is a record of a player who logged in and played a number of games (possibly 0) before logging out on someday using some device.*

**Query requested is**:

Write an SQL query to report the device that is first logged in for each player.

**My solution :**

```
select a1.player_id, a1.device_id
from Activity a1
where event_date = (
    select min(event_date) from Activity a2
    where a1.player_id = a2.player_id
    group by a2.player_id
)
```

Sorry i couldn't get the query properly formatted.

**The problem & question:**

For some reason, it passes the initial tests, but when I submit the solution, I get "Time limit exceeded". Is there a certain logic portion in my query that is inherently bad/inefficient? What could be wrong?

I tried looking it up on the platform but couldn't find any information. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I added explain because some of you asked. I don't understand the full meaning of it, but maybe it helps.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | a1 |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 5 | 100 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | a2 |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 5 | 20 | Using where; Using temporary |

Comment: How does the execution plan for that query look like?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm afraid I don't really know how an execution plan works & what that is, as I'm new to SQL, so I cannot answer to your question

Comment: @brewandrew only add `EXCPLAIN ` your query. Something like `explain select a1.player_id, a1.device_id [rest of the query]`

Comment: @ErgestBasha i did it, see edit

Comment: @brewandrew have you tried any of the answers provided? I see that no index is used in your query. An composite index on player_id ,event_date must speed up things for any of the provided answer

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes. my question wasn't really about a solution that works as I could myself find lots of solutions on the platform, but more of what is wrong with my approach, hence why i did not accept any of the given answers. I am more curious what in my solution's logic is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The query could be written more efficiently (MySQL 8.0 needed) as follows

```
select  player_id, 
        device_id
from ( select player_id,
              device_id,
              row_number() over(partition by player_id order by event_date asc ) as rn 
       from Activity 
     ) tbl
where rn=1;
```

**Edit**.

Add the following index

```
ALTER TABLE Activity  ADD INDEX `pl_eve`(`player_id`,`event_date`);
```

> I am more curious what in my solution's logic is not working properly

`event_date =`  expects that the subquery returns only one value which will not happen due to the group by player_id on the subquery considering that more than two distincts player_id exists on table.

The correct query using your logic would be the query on @SelVazi answer. In the subquery you find the minimum date per each player_id , and use both values on the join condition to find the device_id. An index on (event_date,player_id) would speed things up

```
select a1.player_id, 
       a1.device_id
from Activity a1
inner join ( select player_id, 
                    min(event_date) as event_date
             from Activity
             group by player_id
            ) as s on s.event_date = a1.event_date and a1.player_id = s.player_id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```sql
SELECT 
    player_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(device_id) OVER ( PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY event_date ) device_id
FROM Activity
```

which will hopefully meet your performance requirements.

Letting the engine handle as much as it's optimiser can with the features that it provides, without trying to second-guess it, will typically perform better than the most obvious, heavy-handed solution.

Answer (score 1):

This one can be useful using `inner join`, Its working for mysql <=8

```
select a1.player_id, a1.device_id
from Activity a1
inner join (
    select player_id, min(event_date) as event_date
    from Activity
    group by player_id
) as s on s.event_date = a1.event_date and a1.player_id = s.player_id
```

You can check it from here : https://dbfiddle.uk/ebBce-Fn